# Does a factory reset cause any lasting damage to a Windows PC?

Tags: windows-10, reset, factory-defaults

Just interested, does a factory reset cause any sort of lasting damage to a PC? Does it use up a lot of an SSD's finite write cycles? What computer component does a factory reset affect specifically? Should I not be worried about a factory reset or two harming my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A factory reset does not damage a PC / Laptop in any way.  Factory resets are a good way to solve really bad problems.

Both Microsoft and Manufacturers provide methods to do re-installations and factory resets .

Good SSDs are good for sustained writes for years - usually beyond the life of a computer.

You will not harm your PC.